# HTML5 - Accept / Restrict Filetypes at Upload doesnt work - Alternatives?

Tags: html, upload

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="file" type="file" id="fileA" accept="image/jpeg" accept="text/obj"     onchange="fileChange();"/>
<input name="upload" value="Upload" type="button" onclick="uploadFile();" />
<input name="abort" value="Abbrechen" type="button" onclick="uploadAbort();" />
```

accept doesent works i can upload anyrthing . i need a filter solution to restrict unsecure filetypes.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Anybody can always upload anything anytime to your server. Without even using your website. You always need to be prepared for this server-side.

Comment: Without using my Website . That makes me fear.
You have keywords (which i can search) which help  to protect for it ?

Comment: Nope. Your server is a box which receives HTTP requests and responds with an HTTP response. That is all. Anybody can at all times send arbitrary requests to the server. That's the most basic thing you have to understand about web security.

Comment: Si , i must search for a server side solution, filetyp check with php eventually ?

Comment: Yes, always. HTML input element restrictions are just *helpers* for the user, they are not *security* or *validation*.

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this:

```
<input name="file" type="file" id="fileA" accept="image/jpeg,text/obj"     onchange="fileChange();"/>
```